# ASP.NET MVC adds Validation for non-required fields

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model class "Country" with property "CultureId" that is NOT marked as required. Another class "CountryViewModel" holds the same property "CultureId".

When rendering the "Create" view, I noticed that validation data attributes were added to the "CultureId" textbox, although there were no data annotations added.

I am using

```
@Html.HiddenFor(mode => mode.CultureId)
```

What might be the cause for such a behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

I'm guessing your CultureId is an int.  MVC automatically adds required tags to non-nullable value types.

To turn this off add

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```

to Application_Start or make your int nullable

Comment: Already added that and still the same behavior. I will try to make the int nullable. Thanks

Comment: Good answer. It works to get rid of the `data-required` validation, but then since the Id is an `int` it adds the `data-val-number` which still prevents form submission when trying to create. I could work around it by setting default values like 0, but I shouldn't have to.

Comment: My bad - it works as the validation seems to skip `data-val-number` for hidden inputs

Answer (score 9):

**There are couple of ways to handle this** -
a). Make the property as Nullable like

```
public int? Age  { get; set; }
```

b). Use the below in controller class -

```
ModelState["Age"].Errors.Clear();
```

c). Add to the startup- `DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;`

Comment: Does option (b) solve client-side validation behaviour?  No right, since you're clearing the errors on the postback?

Answer (score 0):

if you can use data annotations, you should check out this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute.aspx

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
[MetadataType(typeof(MovieMetaData))]
public partial class Movie
{
}


public class MovieMetaData
{
    [Required]
    public object Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(5)]
    public object Director { get; set; }


    [DisplayName("Date Released")]
    [Required]
    public object DateReleased { get; set; }
}
```

}

it helps you set validations without models on database side.

Comment: His problem is not about how to set required on a property, but how to avoid the undesired html validation he is running into.
Moreover your way of managing attribute is typical of dynamic data, not the way MVC usually works

Comment: i thought it will be override validation rules, if metadata class will be empty

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ModelState["CultureId"].Errors.Clear();

if (ModelState.IsValid)     
    {
         .....
    }
```

If CultureId is int then it will also give you the desired result...

Comment: This is a bit of a kludge that avoids the real issue involved here. See the [answer from dskh for more](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9941032/237838).